# What terms are used to classify SATA headers?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, terminology

Background: I'm currently trying to replace a SATA header on a solid-state drive. It has a specific header format, and inadvertently buying the wrong one is a waste of time and money, so I'm interested in getting exactly the right one.

What terms are used to classify SATA headers? If I have a header that looks like this:
[image: SATA SSD circuit board]

Then how can I go about searching for its replacement? For example, on Mouser I might look under I/O connectors, and while I know this is an SMT mount, there might be other terms used to describe the termination style—there are plastic pegs, for example, or maybe there's a specific term for the soldering anchors on either side of the header, or a way to describe the way the power and data pins are all in one housing rather than separate header units.

Concretely:

- What is it called when a header has plastic extrusions that punch through the board it's mounted to?
- What is the term for the style of solder anchoring on either side of the connector?
- Is there a specific name for this kind of connector that is more specific than "SATA header"?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for a "Serial ATA plug, 22 contact pins, surface mount, 1.27mm pitch" and see if the one matches with your SSD.

Mainly four attributes are considered when searching a correct replacement for a broken connector:

1. Connector type and Gender (i.e. SATA receptacle, SATA plug)
2. Number of contact pins
3. Contact termination type (removable end)
4. PCB mounting (soldering end)

**Edit**: Found a matching SATA male plug 22pin SMT for the SSD shown in the question.

[image: Top]
[image: Bottom]

Here's the [product page](https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32972717889.html?trace=wwwdetail2mobilesitedetail&gps-id=platformRecommendH5&scm=1007.18499.139690.0&scm_id=1007.18499.139690.0&scm-url=1007.18499.139690.0&pvid=47a0c583-5486-4d91-85b7-e85c7b0e10d3&_t=gps-id:platformRecommendH5,scm-url:1007.18499.139690.0,pvid:47a0c583-5486-4d91-85b7-e85c7b0e10d3&spm=a2g0n.detail-amp.moretolove.32972717889&aff_trace_key=&aff_platform=msite&m_page_id=1913amp-ZSlOe8iXKKOabQWFvL1tnw1567666085916)